# Repeated measures treatment

Tags: repeated-measures, statistical-power

I have an experimental treatment with 16 conditions. In each condition, subjects are given $2 and asked to divide it (in 1 cent increments) between themselves and another entity. The entity is different across conditions (sometimes it is another subject, sometimes it is a charity, etc).

The objective is to find how the recipient affects the amount of giving.

I might not want my subjects to go through all 16 conditions, because I am scared the responses in one round will be affected by responses given in previous rounds if there are too many rounds, or they may get bored.

Consider the below two options:

1) I get 100 subjects to each go through all 16 conditions

2) I get 800 subjects to each go through two randomly selected conditions.

Do I lose a lot of statistical power to determine the treatment effect with case 2 as compared to case 1?

Comment: please state your hypothesis and key objective ?

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: Is your design not crossed at all? That is, are there are 16 different levels of one independent variable?

Comment: Actually, it is crossed (2 x 2 x 2 x 2). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: makes a little better comprehension. needs more clarity.